# Sets on which composition of bijective functions is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition, binary-operations

I have the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a set and $F$ the set of all bijections $f: X\to X$. We consider the composition $f \circ g$ as a binary operation on $F$. Describe precisely for which sets $X$ this operation is commutative.

So, I get that $g$ must also be a bijection if it is a member of $F$, although $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily inverses of each other. I'm thinking the operation is commutative for the identity elements, since each $f$ and $g$ is an injection, but I'm not entirely sure if

1. I'm 100% right about that, and there are absolutely no other sets.
2. How to prove it rigorously.

Any assistance you could offer would be genuinely appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If $X$ has at least three elements $\{x,y,z\} \subset X$ then you can find two bijections $f$ and $g$ which do not commute. Just take $f$ to be the map which swaps $x$ and $y$ and $g$ be the map which swaps $y,z$.

For sets with $0$, $1$ or $2$ elements it is easy to see that bijections (i.e. permutations) do commute (by direct computation):

- the set of bijections of the emptyset has only one ($0!=1$) element (the empty map) and of course any bijection commutes with itself;
- the set of bijections of a set with one element has again only one ($1!=1$) element (the identity map);
- the set of bijections of a set with two elements has two ($2!=2$) elements: the identity and the swap of the two elements: of course they commute.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on the second half of your statement involving sets of 0, 1, or 2 elements, please? In other words, without assuming permutations, or any specific function, how would I go about proving that only sets of 0, 1, or 2 elements commute?

Comment: could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: added an explanation for sets with 0,1 and 2 elements.

Comment: How do you show no other possibilities (finite or infinite) exist?

Comment: In all other cases the set $X$ has at least three elements.

Answer (score 2):

The set $F$ of all bijections $f:\ X\ \longrightarrow\ X$, equipped with composition as a binary operation, is the symmetry group of $X$, denoted by $S_X$. It is isomorphic to $S_n$, where $n=|X|$. So your question boils down to: For which $n$ is $S_n$ abelian? The answer is: Only for $n\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Abelian, not isomorphic, right?

Comment: @BenS. Oops, of course ;)

Comment: The only problem is that we haven't studied permutation groups in my course yet. I know what they are from past study, but I need to prove this without using knowledge of them.

Comment: And we're talking about compositions of bijections.

Comment: In that case Emanuele Paolini's answer above is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Not exactly. He's choosing specific functions that don't commute, not specific sets.

Comment: ...the argument works for *any* set. Pick your favourite one, if you insist one having a specific set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions f:X->X to be permutations of X (this should remind you of a certain group of order n!) When is this group abelian?